# Is it possible to extract both between and within cluster variance estimates from a mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have a three level nested data structure - observations within individuals within countries. I run a mixed model clustering at the country level which gives me an estimate of the between country variance. But I also want the within country variance for each country - is this possible?

Suppose
$$
y_{ij}=\alpha + \epsilon_{ij}
$$
where $\alpha = \beta + \mu_i$ and $\mu_i = \delta_i + \gamma_{ij}$ for participant j in country i

therefore;

$$
y = \beta + \delta_i + \gamma_{ij} + \epsilon
$$

In R I know I can obtain a single variance estimate using

```
fit <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | country/participant))
```

But this only gives me the estimated $\sigma$ for $\gamma_{ij}$, which is the between participant variation nested within countries. What I want is two quantities; the overall between country variance, and the between participant variance WITHIN EACH country.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `fit`? There should be two random effects, `1|country` and `1|country:participant`.

Comment: Yes it does give two random effects. But say I have 30 countries, what I'm looking for is the variance of 1|participant for each country, so 30 estimates, not just a single one.

Comment: jonnyf, unlike what many people think, this is not what is fitted by a nested RE. The assumption of the model above is that the variances within your clusters are all the same. To model different variances per RE / cluster, you could use brms or STAN, or you could model residual variances per group using dispformula in glmmTMB

Comment: For example, the following `brms` model allows different variances for individuals within each country: `brm(y~1 + (1|country) + (1|gr(ind, by = country)), family = gaussian, data = dat)`.

Comment: Or in `lme` from the `nlme` package: `lme(y~1, random = list(~1|country, ind = pdDiag(~country - 1)), data = dat)`.

Comment: Thanks! I assume then that lme4 does not allow separate estimation of varcorr per cluster? Is there any reason why this is so?

Comment: @jonnyf There may be a way of doing it, but it will probably be "hacky". You could ask Ben Bolker, who is a regular on this site and the maintainer of `lme4`.